# no http request with uri in dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, xml, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application using spring mvc and I am new in using spring. I get an exception stating `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCSecurityXML/userinfo] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'` I referenced some of the similar question but could not figure out where I was going wrong can some one help me out. I get the error after the authentication is done.

`mvc-dispatcher-servlet`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.o7planning.tutorial.springmvcsecurity.controller" />

<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

data-source-cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">


   <bean id="myDataSource"
       class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:" />
      <property name="username" value="****" />
      <property name="password" value="***" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">


   <http use-expressions="true">
       <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="isAnonymous()" />


       <intercept-url pattern="/userInfo"
           access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/other/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

       <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

       <form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
           default-target-url="/userInfo" always-use-default-target="false"
           authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" username-parameter="username"
           password-parameter="password" />

       <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccessful"
           delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

   </http>

   <authentication-manager>
       <authentication-provider>
           <user-service>
               <user name="user1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
               <user name="admin1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
           </user-service>
       </authentication-provider>



       <!-- authentication from database -->
       <authentication-provider>
           <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select * from USERS where USERNAME=?"
               authorities-by-username-query="select * from USERS where USERNAME=?" />
       </authentication-provider>

   </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
 <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>        
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/data-source-cfg.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Spring Security Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.o7planning</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCSecurityXML</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVCSecurityXML Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>




    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring framework START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring framework END -->


        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - END -->

        <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

maincontroller

```
    package org.o7planning.tutorial.springmvcsecurity.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MainController {

   @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String welcomePage(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("title", "Welcome");
       model.addAttribute("message", "This is welcome page!");
       return "welcomePage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String adminPage(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("title", "Admin");
       model.addAttribute("message", "Admin Page - This is protected page!");
       return "adminPage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String loginPage(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("title", "Login");
       model.addAttribute("message", "Enter your username/password:");
       return "loginPage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/logoutSuccessful", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String logoutSuccessfulPage(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("title", "Logout");
       return "logoutSuccessfulPage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/userInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String loginPage(Model model, Principal principal) {
       model.addAttribute("title", "User Info");

       // Sau khi user login thanh cong se co principal
       String userName = principal.getName();

       model.addAttribute("message",
               "User Info - This is protected page!. Hello " + userName);

       return "userInfoPage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String accessDenied(Model model, Principal principal) {
       model.addAttribute("title", "Access Denied!");

       if (principal != null) {
           model.addAttribute("message", "Hi " + principal.getName()
                   + "<br> You do not have permission to access this page!");
       } else {
           model.addAttribute("msg",
                   "You do not have permission to access this page!");
       }
       return "403Page";
   }
}
```

userInfoPage.jsp

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>

<html>
<head><title>${title}</title></head>
<body>
   <h2>Message : ${message}</h2>

   <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
      <h3>User Info : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
          | <a href="<c:url value="/logout" />" >Logout</a></h3>  
   </c:if>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing @RequestMapping at the controller level.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MainController {
```

You url will then be:

/SpringMVCSecurityXML/test/userinfo]

Comment: can you please be more specific? because I am guessing I have all the RequestMapping in the main controller.

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your mvc-dispatcher-servlet configuration.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.o7planning.tutorial.springmvcsecurity.controller" />
```

Make sure you import xmlns:mvc.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you so much it does work now. But it also throws the same error again if try to run the project from the start.

Comment: What dou you mean by start project from the start?

Comment: I meant when I close the eclipse and restart IDE and run the project it pops out the same error.